# How to use the clients webcam for recording through a website?

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am building a site and idealy I would like to record the users interaction via their webcam. How do I intergrate webcam recording into my site. I have seen It done with flash. But Im trying to avoid using this. My site is being built using c#, javascript and designed for IE 7 and older.

---

I want to record the videos for later. They are not going to be used for chat e.t.c.

Comment: If your going to put a negative mark at least leave a comment so that I can improve the question!

Comment: What kind of interfacing --chat, streaming video, or pictures? [Google search](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=C%23+webcam+webpage&oq=C%23+webcam+webpage&gs_l=hp.3...1205.4709.0.4933.17.16.0.1.1.0.79.617.16.16.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.UjeVVFOLgxA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=b69722f48e08a1a6&biw=1308&bih=778) shows a lot of links.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using either [HTML Media Capture or WEBRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). Both of these are HTML5 though, so you won't support IE7 (or IE8, or IE9). The alternative is flash. There's a [jQuery plugin](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/control-webcams-with-javascript-jquery/) that enables you to work with Javascript (but still uses flash underneath).

Also, do realize that recording videos of the users without their explicit consent is illegal in many countries.

Comment: besides html5 and flash, there is another option to interact with webcams from a webpage - browser plugin. [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=webcam+browser+plugin) shows some options.